# I need to display categories wise product on seller shop page in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I need to display categories wise product on seller shop page in laravel 8. Display category if seller's product is within category otherwise don't display category.

My blade file

```
<div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h3 class="h3 fw-600 border-bottom">
        <span class="border-bottom border-primary border-width-2 pb-3 d-inline-block">{{ translate('Categories')}}</span>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="aiz-carousel gutters-10" data-items="5">
            @foreach ($categories as $product)
                <div class="carousel-box">
                    <div class="aiz-card-box border border-light rounded hov-shadow-md mt-1 mb-2 has-transition bg-white">
                        <div class="position-relative">
                            <a href="{{ route('shop.visit', $shop->slug. '/products/'.$product->slug) }}" class="d-block">
                                <img class="img-fit lazyload mx-auto h-140px h-md-210px" src="{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}" data-src="{{ uploaded_asset($product->banner) }}" alt="{{  $product->getTranslation('name')  }}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}';" >
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-md-3 p-2 text-left">
                            <h3 class="fw-600 fs-13 text-truncate-2 lh-1-4 mb-0 h-35px">
                                <a href="{{ route('shop.visit', $shop->slug. '/products/'.$product->slug) }}" class="d-block text-reset">{{  $product->getTranslation('name')  }}</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need more information about code so tell me.

Comment: yea I have a question about the code, what does it currently do?

Comment: And why a single category suddenly becomes a product here ? @foreach ($categories as $product)